# Find previous larger occurrences in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data file with different dates and quantities sold of a number of references. Every row is a transaction, with a date and a quantity. I need to find if transactions below a threshold were preceded by larger transactions (in terms of quantity). I already achieved this, but wasn't able to think of a less-convoluted method, which I'm sure exists. I appreciate any hints. Below a fully reproducible example:

```
# load required package
require(data.table)

# make it fully reproducible
set.seed(1)
a <- data.table(ref = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 300, TRUE), dates = sample(seq(as.Date("2017-08-01"), as.Date("2017-12-01"), "day"), 300, TRUE), qty = sample(1:500, 300, TRUE))

# Compute some intermediate tables
#   First one has all records below the threshold (20) with their dates
temp1 <- a[, .(dates, qLess = qty < 20, qty), by = ref][qLess == TRUE,]

#   Second one has all records above threshold with minimum dates
temp2 <- a[, .(qGeq = qty >= 20, dates), by = ref][qGeq == TRUE,][, min(dates), by = ref]

# Join both tables on ref, filter those below the threshold and filter the ones that are actually preceded (prec) by a larger order. THIS IS THE EXPECTED RESULT
temp1[temp2, on = "ref"][, prec := V1 < dates][qLess == TRUE,][prec == TRUE,]
```

Expected results will have, as a minimum, reference and wether it is preceded or not, but preferrably will have quantities and dates (for the below threshold transaction), and the preceding date (as in the provided example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using only the *non-equi join* possibility of `data.table`:

```
setorder(a, ref, dates)
a[qty < 20][a[qty >= 20]
            , on = .(ref, dates > dates)
            , prev.big.date := i.dates, by = .EACHI][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     ref      dates qty prev.big.date
>  1:   A 2017-09-16   5    2017-09-12
>  2:   A 2017-09-27  16    2017-09-19
>  3:   B 2017-09-17  19    2017-09-16
>  4:   B 2017-09-30  19    2017-09-28
>  5:   B 2017-10-04   6    2017-10-01
>  6:   C 2017-08-14   6    2017-08-12
>  7:   C 2017-10-08   1    2017-10-01
>  8:   C 2017-10-24  18    2017-10-22
>  9:   D 2017-10-20   7    2017-10-18
> 10:   F 2017-10-20  11    2017-10-11
> 11:   F 2017-11-23  18    2017-11-22
> 12:   G 2017-11-15  15    2017-11-12
> 13:   H 2017-09-30  14    2017-09-28
> 14:   H 2017-10-05  16    2017-09-28
> 15:   H 2017-10-29  18    2017-10-26
> 16:   I 2017-10-27   9    2017-10-19
> 17:   J 2017-09-23   3    2017-09-17
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward. We set the key to sort by ref and date, then flag "big" orders with a `1`, set preceding big orders to `NA` for small orders and the date for big orders, then fill the big order dates forward. The result has the most recent big order for every order, or a missing value if there is not preceding big order.

```
setkey(a, ref, dates)
a[, is_big := (qty >= 20) + 0L]
a[is_big == 1, preceding_big_date := dates]
a[, preceding_big_date := zoo::na.locf(preceding_big_date), by = ref]
new_result = a[is_big == 0, ]
```